# How to properly cite (and write a paragraph) that a paper is based upon another paper but proposes different contribution?

Tags: publications, citations, writing

I have a paper **A** which is already published. Now I want to write paper **B** which will use data from the same expirement conducted in **A** but with results which were not mentioned in paper **A**.

Basically, paper **A** focused on "which interaction technique is better" and paper **B** will focus on the effects those techniques had on the user.

While **A** was a long journal paper, **B** is planned to be a short poster.

My question is: How can I properly tell the reviewers that this paper uses data from an expirement conducted during another paper? The submission has to be anonymous.

I would write "*This work provides additional insights to the interaction techniques in [citation removed due to anonomity]*" but I have a feeling that this sounds lame and reviewers will feel like "meh..this doesnt sound very sophisticated..."

Also I plan to reuse some images I used in paper **A**, is this allowed?

Comment: If paper A is published, citing it doesn't render the submission less anonymous at least formally. In practice, one would know it is you. But so what?

Comment: I don't know about other areas, but in computer science they seem to be very picky about that. I once had a desk reject where I mentioned the grant number in the acknowledgements.

Comment: adding a grant number to the actual ms or to a paper cited therein is obviously as to say I am the author. In this case you just base your work to be submitted on another work which is published and prone to inspired whoever can read it. As I said, it will be evident that the author is you, but formally the anonymity requirement is fulfilled. This cannot be the base for a rejection, it would be exactly the negation of the principle that anonymous submission is fighting against. Basically might comment is in line with the answer by Aymuos.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I did not know this. I have another worry: I made a video for the reviewers to better understand the paper. The video is anonymized and no author information is given. However, I am speaking in this video. Would this be treated as the same? The formal anonymity is given, and if someone can identify my voice it is no reason to reject?

Comment: Don't mix up requisites. No one knows if a referee wants to reject YOUR work. Yet, the video aspect open a formal issue. I have no idea. I would be able to recognise quite a lot of colleagues based on that, so it might be seen as a formal failure to maintain anonymity. But I wonder if you really need it, giving that in computer science you should not have much of hardcore experiments to show.

Comment: Are the experimental data used in A publicly available (either in A or separately in some repository)? If so, then anyone could have re-used those data to produce B. Then you can write B as if you were some such arbitrary re-user of the data; cite A (and wherever the data are available) and proceed as if you were someone else building on the work in A. It might be that the reviewers can figure out that you're the author of B (if they think no-one else would want to build on A), but you haven't told them, so you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

I think using the data isn't an issue and you can just simply cite the paper. **As far as anonymity goes**, just citing and using that data doesn't disclose the anonymity. Unless there is a rule where an experiment in paper A can not be carry forwarded in another paper, you should be good to go.

To write it properly, refer to some other paper in your domain which does the same. In CS, there are multiple papers churning out solutions for the same data.

**Re-using images** is something I would suggest not to do, newer examples of potential edge cases in the previous paper would hold better. *It generally is allowed unless mentioned explicitly.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how would I write that?
In order to not write a lot of the same things writtein paper A, I need the reader to understand that full implementation details are written in paper A and therefore I don't mention it in paper B.

Comment: So that's upto the reader right? The moment you mention the work carry forwards from paper A, they must go through that. Especially in a poster, you are not expected to fit in all the details. (Am I wrong in saying this?)

Comment: Absolutely not, thats one of the reason Posters exist I guess...
Sadly I still have some trouble figuring out how to proceed in my paper. My main issue is that the whole paper will report a contribution which is based on another paper's experiment. Basically paper A focused on something different than paper B will, but the experiment and the procedure is reused. Paper A has basically some data which was not provided to the reader due to the fact that the focus was different. But the data necessary for B was gathered along with it.
I am not sure how to write this.

Comment: Is there space for an additional appendix ?

Comment: I don't think that an appendix is allowed for posters on my target conference